# os.mkdir() permission denied when running python using shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, python

This is my python file wish to run:
**my_python.py**

```
import os
import numpy as np

os.mkdir(<some path>)

example_code = np.empty(1)
```

This is my script to run this python script: **run_python.sh**

```
python ./my_python.py
```

This is how I run the .sh file:

```
bash ./run_python.sh
```

Then, I get this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<some path>'
```

But when I try running .sh as sudo: **run_python.sh**

```
sudo bash ./run_python.sh
```

I get this python error:

```
  import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

How do I run .py using .sh with the permission to run os.mkdir()?

I want to run: "run_python.sh -> my_python.py -> mkdir()"

Comment: Does `sudo mkdir <some path>` work? How did you add the **numpy** module?

Comment: Running something as `sudo` runs it with root privileges, but running directly runs as your user.  Does your user have the permissions to make that directory.